# Maximized windows on Unity start without covering the sidebar - how can i do that manually?

Tags: unity, 11.04

this is how a maximized window looks when unity runs for the first time:

[image]

and this is how a maximized window looks when i click on the "maximize" button - after i restore it:

[image]

---

Is there a shortcut to make a window get maximized without hiding the siderbar (like in the first screeshot) without making the siderbar always visible?

Comment: lol? that's a bit of a confusing idea :P - it's either one or the other...

Comment: is there, then, a shortcut to hide the sidebar on demand and make it act like a panel (==nothing goes below it) when it is not hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but there is none. The behaviour that you see in the first screenshot is the result of bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/731786. If you want to have the launcher visible, you'll have to set the launcher to be always visible.

Comment: a bug eh? i seem to have a tendency to love bugs lately

thanks :D